# MySQL - add clauses to left join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called properties (p) and another table called certificates (c). There can be more than one certificate allocated against each property or no certificate at all. I need to produce a query that uses a join and only displays one certificate from the certificates table per property. The one certificate that is shown needs to be the one with the most recent expiry date. There is a field in the certificates table named 'certificate_expiry_date'. The simple join would be p.property_id = c.certificate_property but this currently outputs all certificates.

**My Query Attempt**

Here's my query so far;

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.tenancy_property, t.*, p.*, c.* FROM tenancy t
INNER JOIN property p
on t.tenancy_property = p.property_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM certificate
    WHERE certificate_expiry_date > CURDATE()
    ORDER BY certificate_expiry_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) c ON p.property_id = c.certificate_property
WHERE t.tenancy_type='1' AND p.property_mains_gas_supply='1' AND p.property_availability='2' ORDER BY t.tenancy_id DESC LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}
```

This query executes fine but doesn't seem to take into account the left join on the certificates table.

**Table structure for table `certificate`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `certificate` (
  `certificate_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `certificate_property` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `certificate_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `certificate_reference` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `certificate_start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `certificate_expiry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `certificate_notes` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `certificate_renewal_instructed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `certificate_renewal_contractor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`certificate_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=219 ;
```

Comment: Classic "select top n per group".

Comment: I added the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. This question has been answered hundreds of times. Just follow the tag link.

Comment: @BillKarwin He's only selecting one item, so there are no groups.

Comment: @Barmar: Bill is right. OP describes getting a single "latest" certificate from a group of certificates related to a property. It is a classic.latest-n-per-group.

Comment: @MichaelLB, please clarify. Do you need the single most recently added certificate regardless of which property it belongs to, or do you need to query multiple properties with the most recently added certificate for each respective property?

Comment: @BillKarwin I need the most recent certificate for each individual property

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please search the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer with your updated information

Something like this?

(Note: This answer assumes that each property has at least one certificate, or else the sub-query qMostRecentExpire may fail)

```
select
    p.property_id
    , p.* 
    , ( select 
            c.certificate_id 
        from
            certificates    as c 
        where
            c.certificate_property = p.property_id    -- all the cert of this property 
            and c.certificate_expiry_date < CURDATE() -- cert has expired
        order by c.certificate_expiry_date desc       
        limit 1                                       -- most recent one 
      ) as qMostRecentExpire
from
    properties  as p
```

**Updated answer after knowing that some properties may have no certificates**

```
select
    p.property_id
    , p.* 
    , ( select 
            c.certificate_id 
        from
            certificates    as c 
        where
            c.certificate_property = p.property_id    -- all the cert of this property 
            and c.certificate_expiry_date < CURDATE() -- cert has expired
        order by c.certificate_expiry_date desc       
        limit 1                                       -- most recent one 
    ) as qMostRecentExpire
from
    properties      as p
    , certificates  as c                              -- inner join : properties that
where                                                 -- has not cert will be dropped
    p.property_id = c.certificate_property
```

Comment: Please see the update to my post, it may help you improve your answer

Comment: I updated my answer above.  I don't have your tables so I can't test my query.  But it may give you some ideas.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your effort but unfortunately it's not guaranteed that each property has at least one certificate

Comment: Okay I updated my answer again to account for your spec that some properties may have no cert.

Answer (score 0):

If we only need to return one or two columns from the `certificates` table, we can sometimes use correlated subqueries in the SELECT list.

This approach has some performance implications for large tables; but for some use cases, with appropriate indexes available, this can be a workable approach.

```
 SELECT p.id
      , p.somecol

      , ( SELECT c.col
            FROM certificate c
           WHERE c.property_id = p.id
           ORDER BY c.date_added DESC, c.id DESC
           LIMIT 1
        ) AS most_recent_cert_col

      , ( SELECT c.date_added
            FROM certificate c
           WHERE c.property_id = p.id
           ORDER BY c.date_added DESC, c.id DESC
           LIMIT 1
        ) AS most_recent_cert_date_added

   FROM property p 
  WHERE ... 
 ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Please see the update to my post. Does the extra information help improve your answer in any way? I need to return all columns from the certificates table

Comment: @MichaelLB: If you need to return *all* of the columns from the `certificate` table, then, as Bill Karwin indicated in his comment, this is a familiar question which has been answered *dozens* of times.